# Floating point error in C++ code for the number of possible ways to make a team of two members

Tags: c++, sigfpe

I am trying to solve a question in which I need to find out the number of possible ways to make a team of two members (note: a team can have at most two person).
After making this code, it works properly, but in some test cases it shows a floating point error ad I can't find out what it is exactly.

Input:

1st line: Number of test cases 
2nd line: number of total person

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

long C(long n, long r)
{
    long f[n + 1];
    f[0] = 1;
    for (long i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        f[i] = i * f[i - 1];
    }
    return f[n] / f[r] / f[n - r];
}

int main()
{
    long n, r, m, t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin >> n;
        r = 1;
        cout << C(n, min(r, n - r)) + 1 << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Coding style problem: Please don't typedef standard types for the sake of brevity.  `ll` only makes your code harder to read.

Comment: I see no floating point calculations at all in this code. Please provide enough  information for us to be able to reproduce your problem otherwise we can not help you.

Comment: i did submit my code in an online competition portal and they provide us the test cases. I don't know in which case my code fails and why they don't accept my code and showing SIGFPE error.

Comment: Your code appears to be incomplete, as you never assigned a value to `n` in `main()`, but you used `n`.  Did you remove the line of code that assigned a value to `n` before posting your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't getting a floating point exception. You are getting a divide by zero exception.  Because your code is attempting to divide by the number 0 (which can't be done on a computer).

When you invoke `C(100, 1)` the main loop that initializes the `f` array inside `C` increases exponentially.  Eventually, two values are multiplied such that `i * f[i-1]` is zero due to overflow.  That leads to all the subsequent f[i] values being initialized to zero.  And then the division that follows the loop is a division by zero.

Although purists on these forums will say this is undefined, here's what's really happening on most 2's complement architectures.  Or at least on my computer....

At `i==21`:

`f[20]` is already equal to `2432902008176640000`

`21 * 2432902008176640000` overflows for 64-bit signed, and will typically become `-4249290049419214848`  So at this point, your program is bugged and is now in **undefined behavior**.

At `i==66`

`f[65]` is equal to `0x8000000000000000`.  So `66 * f[65]` gets calculated as zero for reasons that make sense to me, but should be understood as undefined behavior.

With `f[66]` assigned to 0, all subsequent assignments of `f[i]` become zero as well.  After the main loop inside `C` is over, the `f[n-r]` is zero.  Hence, divide by zero error.

**Update**

I went back and reverse engineered your problem.  It seems like your `C` function is just trying to compute this expression:

```
   N!
 -------------
  R! * (N-R)!
```

Which is the "number of unique sorted combinations"

In which case instead of computing the large factorial of N!, we can reduce that expression to this:

```
         n
      [ ∏ i ]
        n-r
 --------------------
        R!
```

This won't eliminate overflow, but will allow your `C` function to be able to take on larger values of N and R to compute the number of combinations without error.

But we can also take advantage of simple reduction before trying to do a big long factorial expression

For example, let's say we were trying to compute C(15,5).  Mathematically that is:

```
   15!
 --------
  10! 5!
```

Or as we expressed above:

```
 1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10*11*12*13*14*15
 -----------------------------------   
 1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10  *  1*2*3*4*5
```

The first 10 factors of the numerator and denominator cancel each other out:

```
 11*12*13*14*15
 -----------------------------------   
 1*2*3*4*5
```

But intuitively, you can see that "12" in the numerator is already evenly divisible by denominators 2 and 3.  And that 15 in the numerator is evenly divisible by 5 in the denominator.  So simple reduction can be applied:

```
 11*2*13*14*3
 -----------------------------------   
 1  * 4
```

There's even more room for greatest common divisor reduction, but this is a great start.

Let's start with a helper function that computes the product of all the values in a list.

```
long long multiply_vector(std::vector<int>& values)
{
    long long result = 1;
    for (long i : values)
    {
        result = result * i;
        if (result < 0)
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR - multiply_range hit overflow" << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Not let's implement `C` as using the above function after doing the reduction operation

```
long long C(int n, int r)
{
    if ((r >= n) || (n < 0) || (r < 0))
    {
        std::cout << "invalid parameters passed to C" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // compute
    //    n!
    //  -------------
    //   r! *  (n-r)!
    // 
    // assume (r < n)

    // Which maps to

    //      n
    //    [∏ i]
    //    n - r
    // --------------------
    //     R!


    int end = n;
    int start = n - r + 1;

    std::vector<int> numerators;
    std::vector<int> denominators;
    long long numerator = 1;
    long long denominator = 1;

    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
    {
        numerators.push_back(i);
    }
    for (int i = 2; i <= r; i++)
    {
        denominators.push_back(i);
    }

    size_t n_length = numerators.size();
    size_t d_length = denominators.size();
    for (size_t n = 0; n < n_length; n++)
    {
        int nval = numerators[n];
        for (size_t d = 0; d < d_length; d++)
        {
            int dval = denominators[d];

            if ((nval % dval) == 0)
            {
                denominators[d] = 1;
                numerators[n] = nval / dval;
            }
        }
    }

    numerator = multiply_vector(numerators);
    denominator = multiply_vector(denominators);
    if ((numerator == 0) || (denominator == 0))
    {
        std::cout << "Giving up.  Can't resolve overflow" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    long long result = numerator / denominator;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: how can i get rid of it?

Comment: I just updated my answer to show how to compute larger factorial combinations without overflow.

Comment: And I updated it again to have it scale up to **even higher** values of N and R.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using floating-point. And you seem to be using variable sized arrays, which is a C feature and possibly a C++ extension but not standard.

Anyway, you will get overflow and therefore undefined behaviour even for rather small values of n.

In practice the overflow will lead to array elements becoming zero for not much larger values of n.

Your code will then divide by zero and crash.

They also might have a test case like (1000000000, 999999999) which is trivial to solve, but not for your code which I bet will crash.

Comment: How can i get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

The array syntax as:

```
type name[size]
```

Note: *size* must a constant, not a variable

Example #1:

```
int name[10];
```

Example #2:

```
const int asize = 10;
int name[asize];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what you mean by "floating point error" - I reckon you are referring to the fact that you are doing an integer division rather than a floating point one so that you will always get integers rather than floats.

```
int a, b; 
a = 7; 
b = 2; 
std::cout << a / b << std::endl;
```

this will result in 3, not 3.5! If you want floating point result you should use floats instead like this:

```
float a, b; 
a = 7; 
b = 2; 
std::cout << a / b << std::end;
```

So the solution to your problem would simply be to use `float` instead of `long long int`.

Note also that you are using variable sized arrays which won't work in C++ - why not use `std::vector` instead??